# AWS Lambda RDS - Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

Whenever I test the following code: 
I will receive success on the first log.
The subsequent logs are all showing error.

```
    {
      "errorType": "Error",
      "errorMessage": "Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake.",
      "trace": [
        "Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake.",
        "    at Protocol._validateEnqueue (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:221:16)",
        "    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:138:13)",
        "    at Protocol.handshake (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)",
        "    at Connection.connect (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)",
        "    at data (/var/task/index.js:13:18)",
        "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
        "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:12:24)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
      ]
    }
```

This is the code that i run.

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : "-",
      user     : "-",
      password : "-",
      database : "-"
    });



    exports.handler = async (event) => {
        const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          connection.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            }
            const sql = `INSERT INTO forms VALUES(${Math.random()*10000},2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);`;
            connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {
              if (err) {
                console.log("Error->" + err);
                reject(err);
              }

              resolve(result);

            });
          })
        });


        return {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are storing your connection object outside of the execution context, as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html):

> Objects declared outside of the function's handler method remain
>   initialized...

This means on subsequent calls to your Lambda function, if the function hasn't been destroyed yet due to inactivity (or a new function being spun up due to concurrent calls), then you are reusing the connection object which already has an active connection to your MySQL server. Calling `connect()` on an already established database connection appears to be causing the error you are seeing.

I suggest removing the explicit call to `connection.connect()` and allow the mysql library to establish a connection implicitly if one does not already exist, as detailed in the **"Establishing connections"** section of [the mysqljs documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#establishing-connections).

Comment: This response was helpful. It solved my problem immediately.